# Trouble with key handling and boundary collision in pygame

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

So, first off I am having trouble with the collision handling. Basically I have this code:

```
      x_move = 0
      player_width = 115

   ...


        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                x_move -= 6
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                x_move += 6
                print(x_move)
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a or event.key == pygame.K_d:
                x_move = 0


    if x > display_width - player_width:
        x_move -= 1
    if x < 0:
        x_move += 1

    x += x_move
```

Obviously when a player press 'A' they go left, when they press 'D' they go right. Now the boundary collision is pretty cheap and I've known that since the beginning.

My idea is to detect what frame the player enters, and if the frame (or the frame thereafter) is off screen, minus the width of the sprite (so that half of the player isn't offscreen - it's a spaceship), then refuse the player to go any further.

Now, the other implementation of this actually stopped the player from going any further, however if they kept tapping A or D they would move off screen frame-by-frame.

Currently, however, when they hit the edge, they literally bounce back and reverse direction, and if they hit the opposite direction at the right time they will increment their speed and go faster.

The second problem is that - unless they fully release a key - they can not user a the other key. It prevents them from going anywhere.

Can anyone help me out in a way that helps me understand what is going on behind the scenes? These two issues have been a thorn in my side.

Answer (score 0):

For "they kept tapping A or D they would move off screen frame-by-frame"
You just have to change your code :

```
if x > display_width - player_width + x_move:
    x_move = 0
if x - x_move < 0:
    x_move = 0
```

If you don't understand why, I can explain, but i think it's easy to understand...

However, I don't understand how "they can not use a the other key", what are you wondering at ?

Comment: When this code is used, the player gets frozen at the edges.

Comment: And when the player is going left (K_a) for example, they have to fully release the K_a key before going right. Typically games allow one to overwrite the other in favor of the one recently pressed. It's incredibly impractical to have it this way so I want to be able to overwrite keys with whatever key has been pressed.

Comment: So you want player bounce at the edge ?
You can create a variable which count how many key is pressed